# Add specific element to List when Condition is True

Tags: if-statement, haskell, binary

I want to add a tuple if a bit is set in a 8 bit long number (e.g 146).

My code looks like this and Haskell is just printing to the first true expression:

```
returnPossibleMoves stone = if testBit (look stone) 0 then [(0,-1)] else [(0,0)] ++
                            if testBit (look stone) 1 then [(1,-1)] else [(0,0)] ++
                            if testBit (look stone) 2 then [(1,0)] else [(0,0)] ++
                            if testBit (look stone) 3 then [(1,1)] else [(0,0)] ++
                            if testBit (look stone) 4 then [(0,1)] else [(0,0)] ++
                            if testBit (look stone) 5 then [(-1,1)] else [(0,0)] ++
                            if testBit (look stone) 6 then [(-1,0)] else [(0,0)] ++
                            if testBit (look stone) 7 then [(-1,-1)] else [(0,0)]
```

with look stone = 146 -> 10010010

So my return is just:
`[(0,0),(1,-1)]`

Also is it possible to get rid of the else?

Comment: Possibly an XY problem. Given the rich type system available in Haskell, there is probably a better way of encoding information than treating an `Int` as a bit array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix the code by adding brackets here. Note that the `else` case should just yield an empty list. For example:

```
returnPossibleMoves stone =
    (if testBit (look stone) 0 then [(0,-1)] else []) ++
    (if testBit (look stone) 1 then [(1,-1)] else []) ++
    (if testBit (look stone) 2 then [(1,0)] else []) ++
    (if testBit (look stone) 3 then [(1,1)] else []) ++
    (if testBit (look stone) 4 then [(0,1)] else []) ++
    (if testBit (look stone) 5 then [(-1,1)] else []) ++
    (if testBit (look stone) 6 then [(-1,0)] else []) ++
    (if testBit (look stone) 7 then [(-1,-1)] else [])
```

That being said, it does not look very elegantly. You can use `zip` here to make 2-tuples of where you combine the moves with the bit to test, and then `filter` your list. Finally, you can use `map` to unpack the 2-tuples, and retain the first element. For example:

```
returnPossibleMoves stone = map snd (filter (testBit (look stone) . fst) (zip [0..] moves))
    where moves = [(0,-1), (1,-1), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1), (-1,1), (-1,0), (-1,-1)]
```

or with list comprehension, as [@chi suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60138980/add-specific-element-to-list-when-condition-is-true/60139028#comment106365578_60139028):

```
returnPossibleMoves stone = [move | (i,move) <- zip [0..] moves, testBit (look stone) i]
    where moves = [(0,-1), (1,-1), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1), (-1,1), (-1,0), (-1,-1)]
```

So here the result is:

```
Prelude Data.Bits> returnPossibleMoves 146
[(1,-1),(0,1),(-1,-1)]
```

(if we set `look` to `id`).

This makes sense since for `146` the second, fifth, and eighth bit are set, and thus we return the second (`(1,-1)`), fifth (`(0,1)`), and eighth (`(-1,-1)`) element.

Comment: Minor alternative: `[ move | (i,move) <- zip [0..] moves, testBit (look stone) i ]`

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's the expensive but beautiful way:

```
intSin :: Int -> Int
intSin n = round (sin (pi*fromIntegral n/4))

returnPossibleMoves stone =
    [ (intSin i, intSin (i-2))
    | i <- [0..7]
    , testBit (look stone) i
    ]
```

Why expensive? Because `sin` and floating-point multiply+divide is almost certainly more expensive than a simple lookup-table approach, as described in other answers. But this way is, I think, much more descriptive of the *meaning* of the function... at least to somebody who knows the geometrical interpretation of `sin`.

Of course, you can also make `intSin` quite efficient, and keep the explanatory name and the explanatory implementation of `returnPossibleMoves`; for example:

```
intSin :: Int -> Int
intSin x
    | x .&. 3 == 0 = 0
    | otherwise = 1 - shiftR (x .&. 4) 1
```